# Getting `(.text+0x288): undefined reference` to just about any external Object (from header files), unless compiled a set of `cpp` files together

Tags: c++, oop, linker, g++

I'm trying to wrap elements of this [ascii-art](https://github.com/jgcmarins/ascii-art.git) repo. I'm using `g++ 9.3.0 cpp-17` on ubuntu 20.04. Here's a Tree overview of the dirs -

```sh
├── build
├── in
│   ├── js.bmp
│   ├── socrates.bmp
│   └── woman.bmp
├── LICENSE
├── makefile
├── out
│   ├── js.txt
│   ├── socrates.txt
│   └── woman.txt
├── README.md
├── results
│   ├── js.png
│   ├── socrates.png
│   └── woman.png
└── src
    ├── headers
    │   ├── bmp_body.h
    │   ├── bmp_header.h
    │   ├── bmp_image.h
    │   ├── bmp_process.h
    │   └── bmp_reader.h
    ├── lib
    │   ├── bmp_body.cpp
    │   ├── bmp_header.cpp
    │   ├── bmp_image.cpp
    │   ├── bmp_process.cpp
    │   └── bmp_reader.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

Following my intuition, compiling solely `src/main.cpp`, namely `g++ -Wall src/main.cpp` results in undefined reference errors.

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTouLyj.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x12f): undefined reference to `new_bmp_image()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x162): undefined reference to `bmp_read_header(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned char*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x1aa): undefined reference to `delete_bmp_image(bmp_image*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x262): undefined reference to `bmp_read_body(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int, int, int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x288): undefined reference to `bmp_to_ascii(bmp_image*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x297): undefined reference to `delete_bmp_image(bmp_image*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

compiling every file under `src`, namely `main.cpp` and `lib/*.cpp`, results in success.

Namely the command, `g++ -Wall src/main.cpp src/lib/*.cpp` results a successful complilation.

This might be obvious for experienced c++ programmers, but I'm confused as to what's Really going on. I want to understand why and why not, it did what it did. Although I can barely intuitively understand what's going on, a little more elaboration on this would be awesome :)

Comment: Nothing really more to say than "this is how C++ works". What exactly is unclear to you about "if you don't compile code that's required by the entire application then it doesn't work"?

Comment: @PatXio It is perfectly valid to compile a source file with undefined references so long as you don't try to link it into an executable. You can do this with the -c flag using g++. For more information, research the steps of building an executable from c++ source files (e.g. preprocessing, compilation, and linking).

Comment: oh ok. I see. Thanks, @Nerdizzle for the elaboration. But when you say it is perfectly valid to compile with undefined refs, the process ends with -1, so that means the executable can be compiled to (at least that's what with my case)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What process ends with -1? The compilation process (i.e. g++)?

Comment: Yes @Nerdizzle!

Comment: There must be something wrong with your code. If you're unsure why, feel free to come up with a small reproducible example and open another question.